# Does it make sense to impose a density curve over the bar plot and analyze the mode?

Tags: ordinal-data, discrete-data, density-estimation, mode, barplot

Suppose that my X variable for my probability bar plot is discrete (i.e. not continuous) and ordinal. If this is the case, does it make sense to impose a density curve (apparently this is possible by adjusting the bandwidth) over the bar plot and report the mode from the density? Or is this something that's forbidden since my X variable is discrete?

Thank you,

Comment: Is that a truely discrete measure or a discrete representation of a truely continous variable ?

Comment: @Bernhard I would say this is discrete, since X here stands for 'layer level', which ranges from 1 to 12 (layer 1, layer 2,....layer12). But something like layer 3.7 would make some sense since it would suggest somewhere between layer 3 and layer 4 (layer 1 is the bottom layer and layer 12 is the uppermost layer)

Comment: I can see how a mean in between two levels can make sense. I cannot see that for a mode.